# Find $m$ if $\left({m\choose0}+{m\choose1}-{m\choose2}-{m\choose3}\right)+\left({m\choose4}+{m\choose5}-{m\choose6}-{m\choose7}\right)+...=0$

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

**Question:**

> $$\Big({m\choose0}+{m\choose1}-{m\choose2}-{m\choose3}\Big) + \Big({m\choose4}+{m\choose5}-{m\choose6}-{m\choose7}\Big) + \cdots = 0$$ if and only if for some positive integer $k$, we have

(i) $m = 4k$.

(ii) $m = 4k + 1$.

(iii) $m = 4k - 1$.

(iv) $m = 4k + 2$.

**My Attempt:**

$$(1+x)^m={m\choose0}+{m\choose1}x+{m\choose2}x^2+{m\choose3}x^3 + \cdots +{m\choose m}x^m$$

Replacing $x$ by $i$,

$$(1+i)^m={m\choose0}+{m\choose1}i-{m\choose2}-{m\choose3}i+\cdots+{m\choose m}i^m\\=\Bigg({m\choose0}-{m\choose2}+{m\choose4}-{m\choose6}+ \cdots \Bigg)+i\Bigg({m\choose1}-{m\choose3}+{m\choose5}-{m\choose7}+ \cdots \Bigg)$$

Given that ${m\choose0}-{m\choose2}+{m\choose4}-{m\choose6}+\cdots=-\Big({m\choose1}-{m\choose3}+{m\choose5}-{m\choose7}+\cdots\Big):=p$, thus $(1+i)^m=p-ip=p(1-i)$. Taking mod on both sides,

$$(\sqrt2)^m=|p|\sqrt2$$

Can we conclude from this?

If we take $m$ to be $4k$, say $8$, then we'll have two groups $\Big({m\choose0}+{m\choose1}-{m\choose2}-{m\choose3}\Big)$ and $\Big({m\choose4}+{m\choose5}-{m\choose6}-{m\choose7}\Big)$, and $m\choose8$ will be left as it is.

If $m=4k-1$, say $7$, we'll have two groups and nothing will be left.

But don't know what to do with this observation.

Comment: Hint: You are on the right track. The expression can be written as: $$\frac{1-i}2(1+i)^m +\frac{1+i}{2}(1-i)^m=(1+i)^{m-1}+(1-i)^{m-1}.$$

Comment: Another way to see this is that when you substitute $\binom nk=\binom{n-1}{k-1}+\binom{n-1}k$ and you get: $$2\binom{n-1}0-2\binom{n-1}2+2\binom{n-1}4-\cdots$$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews thanks. What was the motivation for multiplying by $\frac{1-i}2$?

Comment: I solved the equation for your sum equal to $$a(1+1)^m+b(1+i)^n +c(1-1)^n+d(1-i)^n$$ and got $a=c=0, b=(1-i)/2, d=(1+i)/2.$ This is a general trick. If $a_j$ is a sequence of period $k$ then $\sum_{j=0}^\infty a_j\binom nj$ can be written as a linear combination of the $(1+\zeta)^n$ where $\zeta$ runs over all roots of $z^k=1.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews that's a wonderful trick, thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's easier to use the symmetry argument.
$${m\choose n}={m\choose m -n}$$
so
$$
{m\choose n}+{m\choose n+1}-{m\choose m -n}-{m\choose m -(n+1)}=0
$$
and the two terms at distance $n$ and $n+1$ from the beginning and the two terms at distance $n$ and $n+1$ from the end of the summation cancel each other,
so this is true for $m=3, 7, ...=4k-1$.

For example
$$
{3\choose 0}+{3\choose 1}-{3\choose 2}-{3\choose 3}=0
$$
but for $m=4$
$$
{4\choose 0}+{4\choose 1}-{4\choose 2}-{4\choose 3}+{4\choose4}\neq0
$$